# backbone.marionette region and layout

Tags: backbone.js, javascript-framework, marionette

is there a way to specify a template for marionette region?
right now i'm using the layout object to specify a template.

```
 AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({

     template: tmpl

    });

    var layout = new AppLayout();
    App.main.show(layout);

    App.addRegions({
        userInfo: "#userInfo",
        mainMenu: "#mainMenu",
        content: "#content"
    });

    App.mainMenu.show(new mainMenuView.Views.menu());
    App.content.show(new dashboard.Views.main());
```

why i cannot get access directly from my app object to my regions, when i define them inside the layout object?

```
 AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({

     template: tmpl
     regions: {
         userInfo: "#userInfo",
        mainMenu: "#mainMenu",
        content: "#content"
      }
    });

    var layout = new AppLayout();
    App.main.show(layout);

    does not work:
    App.mainMenu.show(new mainMenuView.Views.menu());
    App.content.show(new dashboard.Views.main());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the regions of the layout you put in a region, you can write:

```
App.main.currentView.mainMenu.show(someView)
App.main.currentView.content.show(anotherView)
```

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way to specify a template for marionette region?

This is exactly a Layout - a rendered template with regions in the rendered output.

> why i cannot get access directly from my app object to my regions, when i define them inside the layout object?

The regions in a layout are scoped to the layout's `el`, the same as events. Even if you have a region defined as a "#id" selector, it is still scoped to the layout and will not find anything outside of the layout's `el`.

Also, defining a region on a layout adds the region to the layout, not the application object. If you want the regions defined on the application object, you have to add them to the app object directly.

Comment: Thanks, so you recommend to do it via layout inside a region right?, is the first code where i defined the regions at the app level is not recommended?, i did this to get easy access in my controller to change regions easily, App.content.show(new view);

Comment: it depends on what you need. i don't have enough context of what yuo're trying to do to say which is correct. both are valid uses, and both are useful. layouts are used when you need to render a template at runtime, and attach views to regions in that layout at runtime. app level regions are usually attached to existing HTML that the server generated